# Resetting state causing issues with React mixin

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React component I'm using the [MediaMixin](https://github.com/acdlite/react-media-mixin) to apply classes based on media queries. Here's a simplified example:

```
R.createClass({
  mixins: [MediaMixin],

  render: function () {
    var mediaquery = this.state.media;

    return (
      <Component responsive={mediaquery.small}>
        <input value={this.state.formInput1} >
        <input value={this.state.formInput2} >
        <input value={this.state.formInput3} >
      </Compontent>
    )
  }
});
```

In the above, `{mediaquery.small}` returns `true` or `false` depending on viewport size.

The component also has an initial state used to set some values for a form in the component.

```
getInitialState: function () {
  return {
    formInput1: '',
    formInput2: '',
    formInput3: null
  };
},
```

When the form is submitted/saved, or the form is cancelled, in order to reset the form we use:

```
_cancel: function () {
  this.setState(this.getInitialState());
}
```

This causes issues with the mixin however, as it removes the `state` property containing the mixin's mediaquery.

The solution I'm using now involves resetting the `state` properties related to the form manually, like:

```
_cancel: function () {
  this.setState({
    allowanceType: '',
    allowanceAmount: '',
    allowanceDocument: null
  });
}
```

**Question** - How can I reset the `state` and keep the mixin `state` properties (without manually resetting each form `state` property)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this.

```
_cancel: function () {
    var newState = this.getInitialState();
    newState.media = this.state.media;
    this.setState(newState);
}
```

Remember, that you should treat current state as immutable (just for info).

Answer (score 0):

You could store the initial state of your component inside another function that getInitialState as it's shared with the mixin.

Like:

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return this.componentInitialState();
},
componentInitialState: function() {
  return {
    allowanceType: '',
    allowanceAmount: '',
    allowanceDocument: null
  };
},
cancel: function() {
  this.setState(this.componentInitialState());
}
```